# From what parts does the built Asp web forms application consists?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Can't google with a success an info about: from what parts does the built Asp web forms application consists? In a Debug folder I see only dlls, but as far as I understand the aspx pages and a web.config file should exist. Any links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BIN folder contains the compiled code behind. The ASPX pages and web.config stay in the same place, the root directory of your application.

Further reading:

[ASP.NET Web Project Folder Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[How to: Publish Web Application Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Asp applications, unlike windows forms applications need to be published first.

Right click on your project and click publish. From there pick file system option and publish to wherever you want on your computer.

Those files are the ones you upload to ftp server.